# Creating HTML content with PHP when it's called from an image

Tags: php, html, tracking-pixel

Good morning,

I'm creating a tracking pixel for my emails that uses PHP to add a record to the server.

I want to make this PHP file create an HTML paragraph that will show to the email reciever.

**My question is:** How can I do that when my PHP is set as source of an image?

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<!-- THERE IS WHERE I CALL THE PHP FILE -->

<img src="http://example.com/file.php">

<!-- I want that the PHP file creates a new paragraph here -->
```

My PHP file looks like this:

```
<!-- THIS GENERATES A 1*1 PIXEL (copied from StackOverflow) -->

  $im=imagecreate(1,1);

  $white=imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);

  imagesetpixel($im,1,1,$white);

  header("content-type:image/jpg");

  imagejpeg($im);

  imagedestroy($im);

<!-- AND HERE I WANT TO CREATE AN HTML PARAGRAPH WITH SOME TEXT -->
```

I don't know if that's possible, and I would really appreciate your help,

Thank you very much,

MK.

Comment: That paragraph with text should be printed on your image? (Which doesn't seem to make sense since that image is 1x1) Why not just paste the paragraph as html below your `<img src="http://example.com/file.php">`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! No, the text should be displayed under or over the image (It doesn't matter)

Comment: That php file returns an `image/jpg`. Use a different script to add the paragraph or just add the paragraph directly below/above your `<img src="http://example.com/file.php">`

Comment: Hi! What I want to achieve is to create a new HTML paragraph with a the text of a PHP variable, let's say: ```$text = "hello world"```. I return the image to hide the broken image symbol

Comment: It would be also great to change the text of an existing paragraph if creating a new one is not possible

Comment: "_My HTML file looks like this_" Not possible to use PHP inside a HTML file. PHP will only be executed in a `.php` file (unless you tell your server to parse HTML files using PHP)

Comment: If you want to output text under the image, you need to add it in you HTML code after the `<img ... />` tag and it can't come from `file.php`. If you add _any_ other output than the image contents, you'll get a broken image back (since the browser will count the complete response as image data).

Comment: I noticed that when I send an email in HTM that contains an image with the `src` set to a PHP file, the PHP gets executed. Then, what I want to do is change an HTML paragraph or create a new one with the value of a PHP variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Magnus! Now I see that it's impossible.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the image `alt` with PHP and then return nothing to make it appear on screen?

Comment: The image's `alt` attribute would be set in your HTML file, not the PHP script.